# Querying OracleAQ views from a package in a different schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-aq

I have an OracleAQ multiconsumer queue owned by schema A. As explained in the Oracle doc, there are some views (schema.aq$table_name*) to check the status of the queue table.

I can query these views from another schema through plain SQL or PL/SQL code, but not if this code is wrapped inside a package. The package body refuses to compile with a ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

The second schema has all the necessary rights since I can actually query the view from outside the package.

Answer (score 0):

I performed the following successfully:

1. Created AQ Table (called MY_Q) in Schema A
2. Granted "Select" privs to Schema B to the view AQ$MY_Q
3. Created package (called Q_PKG) in Schema B that selects records from AQ$MY_Q
4. Executed Q_PKG in Schema B

Not sure (without seeing your Schema information) whether there is another priv higher in priority that is restricting your AQ View from being read.
This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811670/how-to-show-all-privileges-from-a-user-in-oracle) shows some information on "displaying" a user's privs.