# Query for All tables and privileges under a specific role in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

What is the query to get all objects with privileges under a specific role.

```
ROLE_NAME  TABLE SELECT INSERT DELETE UPDATE EXECUTE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show all privileges from a user in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811670/how-to-show-all-privileges-from-a-user-in-oracle)

Answer (score 6):

SELECT *
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE GRANTEE='ROLE_NAME';

DBA_TAB_PRIVS describes all object grants in the database.

Or to get the grants for all the roles, you can use below query.

SELECT grantee role_name,table_name,privilege
FROM dba_tab_privs dtp,dba_roles dr
WHERE dtp.grantee=dr.role
ORDER BY role_name,table_name,privilege;

Comment: Note, this does not cover System Privileges like `SELECT ANY TABLE`. Also you can grant a ROLE to another ROLE, this is not covered, either.