# Debugging PL/SQL using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql, oracle11g

Hello I tried to follow this link to debug my pl/sql code using this tutorial

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/plsql_debug/plsql_debug_otn.htm 
but never been able to toggle breakpoint in my sql developer. when I try to reach from Run menu i found it inactive.

any help

Comment: Do you have privileges for debug?

Comment: I don't know. How could I check?

Comment: Privileges could be granted directly or using roles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811670/how-to-show-all-privileges-from-a-user-in-oracle

Comment: also in "Object Browser" you need to right click on package and add "Add debug information"