# Creating Synonym in SQLDevloper- Object name drop down empty?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, synonym

I am trying to create a synonym in using `SQLDeveloper` with this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nEvcZ9nnvc).

When I right click and "create new synonym" I can enter the `Synonym name` and the `Object Owner`, but the drop down menu is **empty** for `Object Name`.

How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: does the user you are logged on as have the create synonym privilege?

Comment: I am not sure how to check this? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811670/how-to-show-all-privileges-from-a-user-in-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query we run to populate the 'Object Name' list.

```
select object_name from sys.all_objects where object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW', 'SEQUENCE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE', 'TYPE', 'SYNONYM')
and owner = :1 order by object_name
```

You have probably selected a schema for which there are no tables, views, sequences, or PL/SQL objects that you have SELECT access to - hence it doesn't appear in YOUR all_object's view.

Run that query in a SQL Worksheet to confirm that indeed, 0 rows are selected.

Then go ask your DBA to grant you privs such that you can work with those objects.