# How to determine table privileges for users that are not in the DBA_TAB_PRIVS table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to determine what table permissions a user has.
The usual way to determine this is to do:

```
 SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE = '<username>';
```

However, the username I am looking for is not in the table DBA_TAB_PRIVS.
But it *does* show up in DBA_USERS, and I know the user HAS privileges because they are able to log in and do SELECT queries.

In fact there are many such discrepancies:

```
 SELECT USERNAME, GRANTEE FROM DBA_USERS u
 LEFT JOIN DBA_TAB_PRIVS p
 ON u.USERNAME = p.GRANTEE
 ORDER BY USERNAME
```

gives:

```
 USERNAME  GRANTEE
 --------  -------
 BOB17     (null)
 DBA       DBA
 DBA       DBA
 DBA       DBA
 DBA       DBA
 JANET5    (null)
 STEVE34   (null)
 SYSTEM    SYSTEM
 SYSTEM    SYSTEM
 SYSTEM    SYSTEM
```

So how can I determine the privileges for users who are not in the DBA_TAB_PRIVS table?

Comment: Are the privileges just granted via roles, rather than directly? [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9811670/266304), if not a duplicate?

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I looked for the users in DBA_ROLE_PRIVS, and indeed the users are granted roles there.  Would you like to write the answer so I can upvote it?