# How to list all users with SELECT ANY TABLE permission in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write PL/SQL scripts to print out all users that have been granted permission to Select Any Table in Oracle database but I still don't know where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT ANY TABLE is a system privilege. So to answer your question you need to query the static data dictionary view [DBA_SYS_PRIVS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/DBA_SYS_PRIVS.html#GUID-384E578D-6506-4419-B943-612A7CF3465F).
You'll need to be a DBA or power user to query this view.

```
select grantee
from dba_sys_privs
where privilege = 'SELECT ANY TABLE';
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on APC's answer, you often need to recursively dig into `dba_role_privs` to find a complete list of users who have access (directly or indirectly) to a privilege.

There are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811670/how-to-show-all-privileges-from-a-user-in-oracle) that go into more detail, and people have written [exhaustive scripts to do this with table and column privileges](http://www.petefinnigan.com/find_all_privs.sql) as well. But here's a lazy version:

```
with rc (grantee, privilege, roles) as (
    select grantee, privilege, null as roles
    from dba_sys_privs sp
    where sp.privilege = 'SELECT ANY TABLE'
    union all
    select rp.grantee, rc.privilege, case when rc.roles is not null then rc.roles || '>' end || rp.granted_role as roles
    from dba_role_privs rp
    join rc on rp.granted_role = rc.grantee
      and nvl(rc.roles,'x') not like '%>' || rp.granted_role || '%' -- avoid cycles
    )
select * from rc
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm very appreciated